# How to make a GET request with parameters to a JSON in Java using Volley?

Tags: java, json, android-volley

I'm doing a school project where i need to parse a JSON and make queries to get specific values. The API in question is this one http://data.nba.net/10s/prod/v2/2018/teams.json and I only want the teams of the "standard" array.

For example I want only the teams which are NBA Franchise, I tried the following:

```
private void loadTeams() {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(application);

    String franchise = preferences.getString("isnbafranchise", "true");

    Uri baseUri = Uri.parse(NBA_REQUEST_URL);
    Uri.Builder uriBuilder = baseUri.buildUpon();

    uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("isnbafranchise", franchise);

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(application);
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, uriBuilder.toString(), new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            List<NBATeam> teamList = QueryUtils.extractFeatureFromJson(response);
            teams.setValue(teamList);

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("Error Volley", error.toString());
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(request);
}
```

But it is the same as without the appendQueryParameter, returns all the taams. I've also tried doing a GET request from Mozilla (http://data.nba.net/10s/prod/v2/2018/teams.json?isnbafranchise=true) and the same result, which makes me think that I'm not doing the query correctly.